# Writing new file via controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the Rails controller, I'd like to write create a new file at `public/my_file.txt` and write the string `This file is my_file.txt` into the file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File.open([full path to your file], 'w') { |file| file.write("your text") }
```

More info via ruby's [file](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) class